# Implement message service using AMQP 1.0 protocol using Red Hat AMQ and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, message-queue, amqp, activemq-artemis, amq

I have to make a demo project which sends a message to and receives a message from a topic/queue using the AMQP 1.0 protocol and Red Hat AMQ (which is built on ActiveMQ Artemis). However, I am unable to find any support or sample code. I tried the example given on the ActiveMQ page, but that's not very helpful. Where can I get an example?

Comment: i mean i have to make a sample demo project using amqp protocol. for which i have to use redhat amq.
But it just needs to be a demo producer/publisher which sends a message to topic/queue using the amqp protocol in artemis. upon which the red hat amq is based.
And also  demo consumer/subscriber. which receives the message.
But i'm failing to find an example online on how to write and configure the publisher and subscriber

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example of exactly what you're looking for in the Red Hat AMQ distribution in the `examples/protocols/amqp/queue` directory. That examples uses the Qpid JMS client library (which uses AMQP 1.0) to send a message to a broker and receive the same message from the broker.